# Using 4G to provide redundancy

Tags: dns, load-balancing, redundancy, 4g

I have a web site running in a small office. The DNS names are managed by Network Solutions. I would like the site to be always available, so I am thinking about getting a backup 4G wireless WAN adapter.

If my primary DSL line goes down, I want all traffic to be forwarded to the IP address associated with the 4G connection. Is there any way to setup a "global" or "virtual IP" that would redirect traffic to my primary IP if it's up, and to my backup IP if the primary is down? Are there organizations that provide such a service?

Comment: Curious why you would go this route when you can get dirt cheap web hosting in redundant data centers... Any compelling reason you are self hosting?

Comment: Yes, amount of DB data is in TBs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with network hardware that supports a failover configuration.

You could setup some sort of script that would ping your router and update a DNS entry if your primary connection went down.

Best answer in my opinion - You could pay a few bucks a month and move your site to a web host where you wouldnt have to worry about this at all.

However, this is probably a question better suited to the server admin/networking sites StackExchange offers.

Comment: I don't think this is workable -- updating a DNS entry will not propagate fast enough.

Comment: @user1044169 - that's not necessarily true. You can set your DNS TTL to something very short which will allow for rapid propagation. Look into Dyn as they specifically advertise allowing clients to set TTLs as low as 30 seconds. Check out this link for some more info: http://dyn.com/dyn-tech-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-ttls/

Comment: Also - check Dyn's managed offerings out - they do offer things like active failover which is essentially what you are looking for, but not sure of pricing or logistics behind it.